# Is the human spirit eternal/immortal?

Tags: nature-of-man

I'm not talking about soul sleep here. I believe that to be absent from the body is to be present with the Lord (2 Cor 5:8) and I believe we are made up of spirit, soul and body. (1 Thessalonians 5:23, Hebrews 4:12, Luke 1:46-47, Zechariah 12:1).

What I'm asking is when God creates the spirit of man does he create it immortal? Like, the spirit of man hasn't always existed like in Greek philosophies but when it does come into existence is it created immortal because from Gen 2:7 I understand that God Himself breathed the breath of life/spirit into Adam and God's breath is uncreated and eternal so shouldn't we be eternal too?

Comment: 'Eternal life' is divine life without beginning, uncreated. An 'immortal soul' as you say, is made by God and shall continue, for ever. Our humanity is mortal and shall die.